# giving zsh a try -- first mystery:

Tags: zsh

All,

Disgusted as I am with bash, I thought I'd give zsh a try, it seems to be well spoken of. So, right off the bat I've run into this brick wall:

```
function z
{
   var="ls -l"
   "$var"
}
```

In bash that would execute 'ls -l', in zsh it gives me "command not found: ls -l"
As I'm absolutely raw with zsh, I have no idea what might be different between it and bash that would cause the above.

Comment: In bash this gives you the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(I assume you meant `$var` on that next-to-last line and not `"$var"`.)*

Zsh does not strive to be completely compatible with traditional Bourne shells. The main incompatible change between sh and zsh is that an unquoted parameter substitution (`$var`) undergoes field splitting and filename generation (globbing) in sh (and ksh and bash) but not in zsh. In zsh, `$var` always expands to a single word (unless `var` is an array variable), here `ls -l`, whereas in sh `$var` would expand to the two words `ls l-`.

You can force field splitting on the result of an expansion in zsh by writing `$=var`, and you can force filename generation by writing `$~var` (`$~=var` or `$=~var` expands both). This is rarely necessary; usually, if you need the expansion to be multiple words, you would store multiple words in the variable.

See also [What is word splitting? Why is it important in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/what-is-word-splitting-why-is-it-important-in-shell-programming/26672#26672)

Comment: Thanks. You know, after trying to get used to the way bash does it, it's going to 'hurt good' to unlearn that and do it sanely.

Answer (score 2):

That would give you command not found in bash as well, simply because by using quotes, you disallow interpolation (as the Perl manual calls it), or re-splitting of $var's contents, so to speak. Therefore, with "$var", there is never more than one argument, and that one argument will be the content of $var.

Comment: Ah! quite right, in bash I had to leave the quotes off. But in zsh

Comment: (damn, forget that 'enter' posts the comment) ... but in zsh if var="ls" (one word) then it would execute, but only with "$var" quoted which is why I quoted it above.